# PyGtk: change image after window's main() method?

Tags: pygtk, python-2.6

I'm using a gtk.Image widget to display a picture in a gtk window. I can set the image to be displayed before I call window.main(), but after I've done that the image won't change any more. Basically:

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk

(...)

window= Window()
window.canvas= gtk.Image()
window.window.add(sprite.window.canvas)
window.canvas.show()
window.canvas.set_from_file("pic1.gif")
window.main()
window.canvas.set_from_file("pic2.gif")
```

pic1.gif will be displayed. Is there a proper way of changing the image (I don't care if I have to use a widget other than gtk.Image)? All I can think of is destroying the window and creating a new one.

Edit:
I realized my mistake... I called window.main() for every window and any window's destroy event called gtk.main_quit(). Had to make slight adjustments, but it works now. Even after calling window.main() :)

Comment: I concur with Magnus Skog. Please post your solution as an answer on this question, and then accept it.

Answer (score 1):

As Rawing hasn't yet accepted his own answer, I'll post it to get this off the top of the unanswered questions page, and to help out anyone skimming this from a search engine clickthrough by providing a comprehensive answer. (Rawing, feel free to post your answer yourself, all the same.)

In your code, you're declaring window as Window(), as opposed to gtk.Window. If you're building in one window, you should not need to do this every time. Create the window once, add what you need to it. If you need additional windows, declare them separately in this module, and call them from code (instead of from main).

Furthermore, don't name your objects with a "window." at the beginning...that just gets overly confusing. Give it a simple name, add it where you need it. Python will do the rest.

A cleaned up version of your code above would probably look like this:

```
window = gtk.Window()
#You may need additional arguments above, such as to make it top level.

canvas = gtk.Image()
window.add(canvas)
canvas.show()
canvas.set_from_file("pic1.gif")
```

Now, just change the image in an event or another "def", like this:

```
def ChangePicture():
   canvas.set_from_file("pic2.gif")
```

Canvas should update the picture automatically.